# Priority order in BFS (Breadth First Search Algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, queue, traversal, breadth-first-search

Starting from the most top node i.e `1`, at node `2`, there will be two adjacent nodes to visit i.e `3` and `4`. Which one should we put first in queue and print? Also please tell why. 
[image]

Comment: Doesn't matter... unless it matters to *you* for some reason.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I am asking from exams point of view. You mean unless it is not explicitly mentioned whether to prioritize bigger number or small number, we can go either way?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing about BFS that requires a specific order.  You generally queue up the adjacent nodes in whatever order you find them.

Comment: @MattTimmermans would you like to add a formal answer?

Answer (score 1):

By its definition BFS should always process 2 and 5 before processing 3 and 4.
In other words the order is determined by the distance from the origin.
For plain vanilla BFS it makes no difference if 2 is processed before 5 or after 5, as it makes no difference if 3 is processed before 4 or after it. 
Note that this in not true for Depth First Search.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to see the previous answer, 5 is not an adjacent node for 1 . 5 will be processed after 3 and 4.

Comment: please exand this into a standalone, correct answer.

Comment: Based on the attached image, I assume the arrows indicate it's a directed graph. For BFS, starting from node 1, the next one to visit is node 2. For node 2, there are 2 adjacent nodes, it's up to the implementer to decide which one to visit first (normally it doesn't matter unless there is a reason such as a node with a larger value needs to be visited first).

Comment: there's an edit button to edit the post.